# CakePHP 3.0 Role Based Access Control

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am having a hard time finding assistance on securing my application.  I want to create a role based system, in CakePHP, that would allow me to assign users to a role(s), assign permissions to a role, and use the roles to control who can see/do what on my application.  I recall there being something you could use in CakePHP 2.X but I can't find anything in 3.0.  Is this still supported?  Is there a recommended way to do this?  In particular, I need to know the table structure, so I can add them to my database diagram.

thanks

Comment: Dangerously close to being offtopic, asking to find some software...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [TinyAuth](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth) plugin by dereuromark or the [official ACL plugin](https://github.com/cakephp/acl) by cakephp.

> The ActionsAuthorize & CrudAuthorize adapter available in CakePHP 2.x
>   have now been moved to a separate plugin cakephp/acl.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#authorization

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any official docs for the ACL plugin, it's kind of the unwanted child of the CakePHP framework, nobody really wants it, but it's there, so its being hidden in the basement, in the hope that people will eventually forget about it. An inofficial ACL example can be found at **https://github.com/mattmemmesheimer/cakephp-3-acl-example**.

Comment: Why is this being shunned?  Is it better to just write my own role bases system?

Comment: Did you check TinyAuth as I wrote above? Works really well.

Comment: @jason I've exaggerated a _little_ bit of course :) But generally there isn't much development around it, as it doesn't seem to be widely used amongst the active commiters, and because it's pretty much considered feature complete. It should however be safe to use it (in case you really need full blown DB backed per-row ACL!), issues are being fixed, and I think it's safe to say that compatibility for future 3.x versions will be ensured (that's not an official statement though).

Comment: Great, thanks.  I will check out both TinyAuth and ACL.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you guys know how can I upgrade cakephp 2.x acl to cakephp 3.x - I am trying to upgrade our age-old cakephp 2.x application to 3.x but since it uses acl heavily, I have no idea where to begin